# condaコマンドにおけるOSerrorについて

Tags: python, python3, linux, ubuntu, anaconda

anacondaを用いてpython環境を扱っています。
一部ライブラリをダウングレードしようとshellにて以下のコマンドを入力したところ

```
conda list
```

エラーが発生しました。

エラーメッセージは以下の通りです。

```
OSError: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

解決策を模索しましたが、解決には至りません。
大変恐縮なのですが、解決方法がわかるかたがいましたら、ご教授いただきたいです。

---

環境

- python 3.6.8
- Ubuntsu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- anaconda 4.7.5

Answer (score 0):

libiconvの共有オブジェクトが存在しないようなので、condaでlibiconvを入れたらどうでしょうか。

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge libiconv
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775441/chef-installing-uwsgi-libiconv-so-2-no-such-file-or-directory